# How to get feedback about our prices

Tags: client-relations, business, pricing

I sent prices to the client and did't receive a feedback.

What is the best way to ask, is my price ok for them?

How do you think a phrase like **"How do you like our prices?"** would work?

Answer (score 3):

Don't say anything.

Instigating any further communication about pricing puts you in a *very* weak negotiation position. *Never* apologize for or question your pricing to a client.

If anything, ask if the client is ***ready to move forward*** and provide the non-refundable deposit.

Always assume your pricing is accepted unless told otherwise. But, of course, don't begin any work until the client gives the green light, provides a deposit, and signs the contract.